# VHDL: Code to put a numeric value in a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR variable

Tags: vhdl, numeric

I would like to enter a number in a a variable of type STD_LOGIC_VECTOR but I have problems with the compiler.

```
signal cl_output_ChA :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (16-1 downto 0);

cl_ouput_ChA <= 111111111111111;
```

The compiler give me these two messages:

- The integer value of 111111111111111 is greater than integer'high.
- Type of cl_output_ChA is incompatible with type of 111111111111111.

could anyone give me a proper code line to put in this variable a particular numeric value?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Could anyone create a tag called 'code', this could indicate someone asking for a piece of code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, the error is because the number as you have written it is treated as an integer.

I take that you mean for the number to be binary? In that case use "".

```
cl_ouput_ChA <= "111111111111111";
```

You can also go for hex, x"".

```
cl_ouput_ChA <= x"ffff";
```

If you want to assign an integer to an std_logic_vector, then you can do it like this.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_Logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_STD.all;

...

cl_ouput_ChA <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(12345, ch1_ouput_ChA'length)); -- natural
cl_ouput_ChA <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(12345, ch1_ouput_ChA'length));   -- signed
```

Where 12345 is the integer (or natural) and 16 is the width.

Comment: I suposse 16 are the numbers of bits that are needed to represent that number, isn´t it?

Comment: @Peterstone: Yes, but see my edit which shows a way which will scale if you change the length of your vectors for any reason.

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the edit to add in the 'length attribute.

Answer (score 7):

You could also do the following, which puts a 1 in each bit.

```
cl_ouput_ChA <= (others => '1');
```